# Changing the background from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, api

im using the Sketchfab API, and i want to change the background inside the iframe. My code only works showing the right information of the 3D Model or changing the background, but no both. If someone can take a look and say me something... 
Sorry for my bad English and thanks.
That is the part of jQuery

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
  $(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
    switchBackground();
};
function switchBackground() {
  var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
  if (backgroundImage) {
    $('iframe').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');   
  } 
}
function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
 </script>
```

And this the HTML part:

```html
<body>
<iframe class="visor" id= "visor" style= "border:0" src=" 

transparent=1&amp;
" 
  
  width="500" height="300"    >
    
            </iframe>
<div class="container">



  <div id="elmenu" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Reja <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <button class="secundarios" id="R1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rxwVStQ.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
  <button class="secundarios" id="R2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pNmbRna.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
      </ul>
    <div id="elmenu" class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Adornos arriba <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <button class="secundarios" id="AAR1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/3ij52Qo.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AAR2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABHPWKx.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AARN"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wz2YimL.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
      </ul>
   <div id="elmenu" class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Adornos medio <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <button class="secundarios" id="SIN"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rF60Iar.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AM"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Kzit2d.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AMC"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/g66ylts.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AC"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/416XksG.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>    
      </ul>
   <div id="elmenu" class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Adornos abajo <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <button class="secundarios" id="AAB1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/3ij52Qo.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AAB2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ABHPWKx.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
    <button class="secundarios" id="AABN"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wz2YimL.png" width="50px" height="50px" ></img></button>
      </ul>
   <div id="elmenu" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-ttc" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Cambiar fondo <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">        
 <input class="inputfile" id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" ></input>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

    
    <!-- Initialize the viewer -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = document.getElementById('visor'); 
      urlid = '47e0f04b958748a5880e35090d0775f0';
   

    // By default, the latest version of the viewer API will be used.
    
     
 //declarar un nodo con el nombre que quieras
var buttonReja1 = document.getElementById( 'R1' ),
            buttonReja2 = document.getElementById( 'R2' ),
            buttonAdornoarriba1 = document.getElementById( 'AAR1' ),
   buttonAdornoarriba2 = document.getElementById( 'AAR2' ),
   buttonAdornoarribaNo = document.getElementById( 'AARN' ),
            buttonAdornomedio = document.getElementById( 'AM' ),
            buttonAdornoabajo1 = document.getElementById( 'AAB1' ),
   buttonAdornoabajo2 = document.getElementById( 'AAB2' ),
   buttonAdornoabajoNo = document.getElementById( 'AABN' ),
   buttonAdornomedio2 = document.getElementById('AMC'),
   buttonAdornoCirculos = document.getElementById('AC'),
   buttonSinAdornos = document.getElementById('SIN'),
   
            // Nodes
            nodeReja1,
            nodeReja2,
            nodeAdornosArriba1,
   nodeAdornosArriba2,
   nodeAdornoMedio,
            nodeAdornoAbajo1,
            nodeAdornoAbajo2,
   nodeAdornoMedio2,
   nodeCirculos,
            // Objects
            objReja1 = 'reja1 pos1',
            objReja2 = 'reja2 pos1',
            objAdornoArriba1 = 'adornoarriba1 pos1',
   objAdornoArriba2 = 'adornoarriba2 pos1',
   objAdornoMedio = 'adornomedio pos1',
            objAdornoAbajo1 = 'adornoabajo1 pos1',
            objAdornoAbajo2 = 'adornoabajo2 pos1',
   objAdornoMedio2 = 'Torus001',
   objAdornoCirculos = 'adornoscirculos',         
      //lo mismo para el otro objeto
 
    // Alternatively, you can request a specific version.
      client = new Sketchfab( '1.0.0', iframe );

    client.init( urlid, {
        success: function onSuccess( api ){
            api.start();
            api.addEventListener( 'viewerready', function() {

                // API is ready to use
                // Insert your code here
                console.log( 'Viewer is ready' );
   
              api.getNodeMap( function ( err, nodes ) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log(nodes);
      for(var prop in nodes){
        if(nodes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
         
 if ( nodes.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                                    // Check nodes against object names
                                    if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objReja2 ) {
                                        nodeReja2 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                                        console.log( nodeReja2 );                       
                                    }
                                      else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objReja1 ) {
                                        nodeReja1 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                                        console.log(nodeReja1);
                                      }
           else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoArriba1 ) {
            nodeAdornosArriba1 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
            console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornosArriba1 );          
           }
             else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoArriba2 ) {
              nodeAdornosArriba2 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
              console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornosArriba2);          
             }
               else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoMedio ) {
                nodeAdornoMedio = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornoMedio);
               }
                 else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoAbajo1 ) {
                  nodeAdornoAbajo1 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                  console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornoAbajo1);
                 }
                   else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoAbajo2 ) {
                    nodeAdornoAbajo2 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                    console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornoAbajo2);
                   }
                    else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoMedio2 ) {
                     nodeAdornoMedio2 = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                     console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeAdornoMedio2);
                    }
                     else  if ( nodes[ prop ].name === objAdornoCirculos ) {
                      nodeCirculos = nodes[prop].instanceID;
                      console.log( 'red head node: ' + nodeCirculos);
                     }
            //button event
            buttonAdornoarriba1.addEventListener( 'click', function() {                                          
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornosArriba2);
                                            api.show(nodeAdornosArriba1);  
                                        });
                                    }
         buttonAdornoarriba2.addEventListener( 'click', function() {  
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornosArriba1);
                                            api.show(nodeAdornosArriba2);   
                                        });
                                    }
         buttonAdornoarribaNo.addEventListener( 'click', function() {                                          
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornosArriba1);
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornosArriba2);           
                                        });
                                    }
         buttonAdornoabajo1.addEventListener( 'click', function() {                                          
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoAbajo2);
                                            api.show(nodeAdornoAbajo1);      
                                        });
                                    }
         buttonAdornoabajo2.addEventListener( 'click', function() {                                           
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoAbajo1);
                                            api.show(nodeAdornoAbajo2);           
                                        });
                                    })
         buttonAdornoabajoNo.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                                           
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoAbajo2);
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoAbajo1);           
                                        });
                                                
         buttonReja1.addEventListener( 'click', function() {     
                                            api.hide(nodeReja2);
                                            api.show(nodeReja1);
                                        });
                                    buttonReja2.addEventListener( 'click', function() {  
                                            api.hide(nodeReja1);
                                            api.show(nodeReja2);
                                        });
         buttonAdornoCirculos.onclick =  function(){
          let exterior = true;
          return () => {
          if (exterior) api.hide(nodeCirculos);
          else api.show(nodeCirculos);
          exterior = !exterior;
            };
          }();
          buttonAdornomedio.addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoMedio2);
                                            api.show(nodeAdornoMedio);
                                        });
                                    buttonSinAdornos.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoMedio2);
                                            api.hide(nodeAdornoMedio);
           api.hide(nodeCirculos);
                                        });
                                    buttonAdornomedio2.onclick =  function(){
          let adorno = true;
          return () => {
          if (adorno) api.hide(nodeAdornoMedio2);
          else api.show(nodeAdornoMedio2);
          adorno = !adorno;
            };
          }();
          buttonAdornomedio.onclick =  function(){
          let adorno1 = true;
          return () => {
          if (adorno1) api.hide(nodeAdornoMedio);
          else api.show(nodeAdornoMedio);
          adorno1 = !adorno1;
            };
          }();
});
   
     
                                        }
          

          
                                        })
                                        
    </script>
```

I also leave here the entire code : https://gist.github.com/TechnoOscuro/cc4556dd484e89b2b03d43a06a8b6254#file-sketchfabapitest-html

Comment: You should add your code directly to your question, without the external link. Otherwise your question might get downvoted.

Comment: if i add the code directly, it says there is so much code :(

Comment: Find a way to shorten it. Break it down to where the issue is.